# I want show HTML element when the specific text is in the description

Tags: javascript, html

I got code like this:

```js
function show() {
  var txt = document.getElementsByClassName("descriptiontxt --block")[0].innerText;
  if (txt == "TXT element xyz") {
    document.getElementsByClassName("showelement").style.visibility = "visible";
  }
}
show();
```

```html
<section id="mainsection" class="mainclass">
  <div class="header --name">
    <h1 class="headtxtelement">TXT element xyz</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="descriptiontxt --block">
    <ul>
      <li>TXT element xyz</li>
      <li>Text line 1</li>
      <li>Text line 2</li>
      <li>DText line 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <a class="showelement" href="x">ELEMENT I WANT TO SHOW</a>
</section>
```

I want to show a "a class="showelement" when the text in div class "header --name" or  is "TXT element xyz"

A try something like this - but still not working

```js
  function show() {

var txt = document.querySelector("mainsection")[0].innerText;
if (txt === "Test") {
  document.querySelector(".showelement").style.visibility = "visible";
}
  }
  show();
```

Comment: A simple `console.log(txt)` would have shown you, that `txt` is not _just_ `TXT element xyz`, so of course that comparison does not yield true.

Comment: And `document.getElementsByClassName("showelement").style.visibility = ...` will throw an error. Two lines before you still knew how to access _one_ specific element out of what getElementsByClassName returns, did you already forget by now ...?

Comment: `==` is an exact match (with some type coercion that's not important here), have a look at `includes()` [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("showelement").style.visibility` will not work at all. `getElementsByClassName` will not return an element but an HTML Collection Object which is a list of elements. An iteration or an index is needed.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to use the correct class for `div`:

   ```
   var txt = document.getElementsByClassName("header --name")[0].innerText;
   ```
2. Inside the if block, use `[0]` for `getElementsByClassName` function as this returns array:

   ```
   document.getElementsByClassName("showelement")[0].style.visibility = 'visible'
   ```